# Potential indictment of Assange and jurisdiction

Tags: us-constitution, jurisdiction, extradition, indictment

I was discussing this sealed indictment against Julian Assange with my wife and she was making the argument that this is not an attack against freedom of the press as granted by the Constitution.  She was making the case to me that because Assange has made public statements about his desire for Hillary Clinton to not be POTUS and the strategic release of documents with intent to harm her election, that Assange could potentially be indicted on the below:

https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/52/30121

I get that the public release of these damaging documents could be argued as "contributions", and that intent makes all the difference here. It seems rather clear that as worded Assange is in violation of this law.

The part where I am confused is how such a law could actually be valid against foreign nationals, especially foreign nationals that have never operated or even set foot in the United States. Does jurisdiction for such a law extend potentially to any action deemed harmful to a US election anywhere in the world?

If so then what would stop a country like Iran from passing a law stating that a foreign national depicting an image of the prophet Mohammed is illicit and harmful to the people of Iran? What would stop them from demanding extradition of any person in the world?

Comment: As to the last paragraph: they can pass any law they like, and they can demand the extradition of whoever they like.  It doesn't mean that any other country has to comply with such a demand.

Comment: It is in general  possible for the US, or any other country, to pass a law that applies to foreign nationals and/or outside the country.  You might like to read about [extraterritorial jurisdiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterritorial_jurisdiction). ( Of course, actually being able to enforce such a law is another story entirely, and may be largely a matter of diplomatic or military influence.) I don't know whether this particular statute is extraterritorial

Comment: Related: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/17560/how-long-an-arm-does-the-u-s-have-against-foreign-violators-of-u-s-law-outsi/17565#17565

Comment: "It seems rather clear that as worded Assange is in violation of this law": how?  A statement about his desire for someone not to become president is not a contribution or donation of a thing of value, nor is it an electioneering communication as that phrase is defined.  The same is true of the release of documents online.

Answer (score 3):

> The part where I am confused is how such a law could actually be valid against foreign nationals

It is valid against them because it explicitly applies to them.  In fact, it applies only to them: The title of the section in question is "Contributions and donations by foreign nationals," and the text of the section reflects that.

A campaign contribution must be received by the campaign organization to be a campaign contribution, so there is the source of US jurisdiction: A foreign person, even one who has never [set foot in](https://archives.cjr.org/language_corner/missed_step.php) the US, can nonetheless be subject to US jurisdiction because of an act whose effects are felt in the US, regardless of where in the world the act was initiated.

The restrictions on "electioneering communications" are implicitly concerned with communications inside US territory, but (even ignoring that) they concern only "broadcast, cable, or satellite" communications, which implies that only audio and video communications are in scope.  Publication of documents is not covered by this law.  So if Assange escapes liability under this law it is likely to be because his acts were not prohibited by it, not because of his citizenship or location

Comment: I guess when worded like that it seems a stretch to prosecute him under this law. Perhaps then they are trying to prosecute him against the espionage act? Seems like the Pentagon Paper fiasco all over again.

Comment: @maple_shaft of course, the presence or absence of any implication is rather easier to argue in court than other aspects of statutory interpretation, and if a court hasn't found one way or another then the government can reasonably prosecute on the theory that the law applies everywhere (for presidential and vice-presidential elections) and to media of communication that did not exist when the law was written but may be subject to inclusion by analogy. I think it rather more likely that they would succeed under the espionage act, but I haven't read it so it's just a guess.

Comment: I also note that the referenced definition of "foreign principal" from title 22 comes from a law that concerns activities "within the United States."  Congress seems to want to be careful about criminalizing statements of opinion by foreign people in foreign places, and with good reason. On the other hand, it's also reasonable to seek to prevent foreigners from influencing federal elections.  Finding the border between the two may be difficult.

Comment: "to media of communication that did not exist when the law was written" IANAL but if I am reading this right, it looks like it says it was codified into law in 2002?  The Internet as a media of communication was well established already at this point so I would think that it would be a poor argument.

Comment: @maple_shaft you're right. The term "electioneering communication" was introduced by the 2002 amendment.  I had assumed incorrectly that it was in earlier versions of the statute.

Comment: *It is valid against them because it explicitly applies to them.* Is not the issue less about the language of the statute than about the broader jurisdictional limits of each particular state, subject to constraints such as international norms and the rule of the law? *A foreign person... can nonetheless be subject to US jurisdiction because of an act whose effects are felt in the US...* Would not such a precedent, due to its broadness and vagueness, not support the arbitrary expansion of the powers of any state toward persons of another?

Comment: @epl what line of reasoning do you suggest leads to the conclusion that a state has no power to ban material contributions to its political campaigns by foreigners?  Certainly there is a precedent that states may impose criminal penalties for acts outside their territorial jurisdiction by foreigners that harm the state's interest in some way or another, such as passing state secrets to an enemy.  It's not arbitrary if the ability to assert jurisdiction depends on a criterion such as harm to the state's interest.

Comment: @phoog, Acting with an intent to harm the interest of foreign states is a matter of course. Those in US government seek daily to undermine US enemies. I would understand the extent of a state's power that would be recognized by other states to be constrained to its recognized territorial extent and to those persons of its citizenship. Would it not be convenient if the US could levy taxes not only on persons living within its territory and on its citizens living abroad, but indeed on every person in the world, yet would it not also be incompatible with any normal or practical application law?

Comment: @epl obviously the criterion of harm isn't absolute.  But states do a lot of things that are illegal.  If the US interferes in a foreign election, nobody can prosecute the US.  But I also imagine that a US officer who had been responsible for the interference would be liable to criminal prosecution in that country.  "recognized by other states to be constrained to its recognized territorial extent and to those persons of its citizenship": so if a non-Belgian shoots a bullet from French territory into Belgian territory and injures someone, Belgium cannot seek to prosecute?

Comment: @phoog, The broad issue is whether a state has blanket power to seek prosecution for a foreign person for acts committed in foreign territories. Generally, it seems that such blanket power would undermine any hope of functional international relations. Taking your example, both Belgium and France have legal codes that proscribe unjustified homicide, so prosecution for any credible allegation generally should not be met by overarching obstacles.

Comment: @phoog, Your analysis of the immediate case seems to adopt the assumption that the essence of US government grievances against Assange amount to electoral interference. I assume you are referring to leaks that harmed Clinton's personal reputation closely preceding the election victory of Trump in 2016. News of the Assange indictment broke in 2013, and the charges were related to espionage, in particular, the publication of state secrets, for example, those related to armed engagements in Iraq.

Comment: @epl I'm talking about power to prosecute extraterritorial acts with non-extraterritorial consequences.  I'm adopting the assumption of electoral interference because it is raised in the question.  I don't think it's valid.  But the idea that Assange could be prosecuted under the cited law requires a finding that his acts constitute election interference, so that's the context of this discussion.

Comment: @epl More generally, the proposition that a foreigner on foreign soil committing crimes remotely is beyond a country's jurisdiction just doesn't hold water.  Do you imagine that Assange could escape US criminal liability for e.g. defrauding US retirees of their life savings simply by being a foreigner and operating from a foreign country?  Of course not.

Comment: @phoog, Again, the hypothetical cases you raise are rather unremarkable disputes arising from one person alleged to have harmed the private interests of another that would be protected by most any jurisdiction. Toward the opposite extreme, the Assange indictment has revolved around anti-espionage laws, whose general enforcement as such would appear to comport neither with established norms or a coherent conception of international law and relations. Electoral interference is an intermediate example representing a creeping expansion of the claimed powers of a particular state.